# Is Independent University of Moscow recognized?

Tags: mathematics-education

What graduate schools recognize the degree from [Independent University of Moscow](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fium.mccme.ru%2Fenglish%2F&ei=vEDTU4rfL4HOygPSh4CoCQ&usg=AFQjCNEGgcSJFc1Q-REuhCm8avQIie3oxg&sig2=x4q901kklOlWdaJEcJbLVA&bvm=bv.71778758,d.bGQ)? It is not a university strictly speaking and their degree doesn't have any official status in Russia, but they claim on their website that *Harvard* recognizes their degree. Also *MIT* [sends their students](http://math.mit.edu/academics/undergrad/opportunities/international/) for one semester to study at this university, this program is called [Math in Moscow](http://www.mccme.ru/mathinmoscow/).

Anyway their program in math is the most difficult in Russia and the degree is hard to obtain. Many students study there simultaneously while studying in their main university. Will obtaining the degree increase one's chances to be accepted at a graduate school in the US or Europe?

Comment: The Math in Moscow program takes place at IUM, but Math in Moscow (taught in English during the day, for students from the US and Canada -- not just MIT -- and lasting a semester for each student) is, from a student's perspective, completely separate from the IUM courses offered to local students (all taught in Russian in the evenings to accommodate the schedules of students officially attending other universities in Moscow). The students don't overlap. Why ask about this here instead of simply writing to the people at IUM? Have you read their FAQ page http://www.mccme.ru/ium/FAQ.html?

Comment: I have read the FAQ. I ask here because I think that there might be people that make decisions whether to admit a particular student at a graduate school or not, and these people might have considered students that had the degree from IUM.

Comment: @Adeel: You say HSE offer *a well-respected bachelor's degree* in math. They have good team of teachers, but none of the schools have ever accepted someone with a bachelor degree  from HSE. They have taught math only for four years, and this year the first class graduated with bachelor degrees. And one of the teachers (Verbitsky) wrote in his blog, that this class was "very weak."

Comment: In fact, the first class graduated from HSE with a bachelor's degree in math in 2012, and the second one in 2013.  This year, it was the third.  And, of course, a number of students with these degrees were accepted to Masters and Ph.D. programs over the world.

Comment: Of course! Hail to Russia!